# jQuery easing vs CSS3 transition - Is there an exact equivalent smoothing?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css

I am using jQuery animate together with CSS3 transition.

The problem is I couldn't find an equivalent smoothing animation. Is there any?

The closest I got is this (jQuery easeOutQuad and CSS3 default easing).

CSS:

```
#div1 { transition: width 0.5s; }
```

jQuery:

```
$('#div2').animate({'width': 200}, 500, 'easeOutQuad');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bzw4q/

But they are still different.

I want both to animate together at the same time (using any good easing algorithm). Is that possible?

Comment: You can define [transition timing functions using CSS3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/#transition-timing-function-property) as well; was that what you were asking for?

Comment: Why not add a class-name with jQuery, and use that to start, and synchronize, the animation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `swing` and `ease-in-out` > http://jsfiddle.net/et6Hg/

I think you have better chances :)

Comment: Thank you Ussama! The good thing is 'swing' is the default, the down side is you need to multiply the jQuery duration by 0.96. But it's good enough thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Also here http://easings.net to get the matching cubic-bezier.